# Unknown entity issue for joined subclass when using annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, joined-subclass

I met exception when using annotated joined subclass, i don't know how to correct it, please help. 

Exception is: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: B

Code:

Class A

```
@Entity
@Table(name="table_a")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)   
public class A {
    // uses composite key
    @Id
    @Column(name="sid")
    private String sid;

    @Id
    @Column(name="uid")
    private String uid;

    .....
}
```

Class B

```
@Entity
@Table(name="table_b")
public class B extends A {
    // inherited sid and uid from A
    @Id
    @Column(name="xid")
    private String xid;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    ......
}
```

Tables

```
create table_a(sid varchar, uid varchar);
create table_b(sid varchar, uid varchar, xid varchar, name varchar);
```

Hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        .....
        <mapping class="A"/>
        <!-- no need to map B here, right?
        <mapping class="B"/>
        -->
        .....
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

TestClass

```
public class HibernateTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        B temp = new B();
        temp.setSid(1);
        temp.setUid(2);
        temp.setXid(3);
        B target = session.get(B.class, temp);
        System.out.println("---------------" + target.getName());
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
   }
}
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: B
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `<mapping class="B"/>` commented out with a question asking if it's needed. You need it.

Comment: but if I don't comment out B, there will be another exception: <br> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.mapping.JoinedSubclass cannot be cast to org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass

Comment: @liuhebing: That's because you have it mapped wrong. You can't have an id property in B if it extends A, which already has an id. Also, you can't have two id's in A. Read up on [mapping id properties](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-identifier) and on [mapping composite primary keys](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2177) with annotations.

Comment: @liuhebing: On an unrelated note, all of the @Column annotations shown above are superfluous. Remove them all, and everything will work exactly the same.